# Может ли объект пересечь границу адресного пространства?

Tags: c++, c

В `C` и `C++` память адресуется побайтово. Если верить `Стандарту`, начало многобайтового объекта - это адрес его самого младшего байта. То есть - байта, который расположен ближе всех остальных байтов объекта к началу адресного пространства (к 0).

Мой вопрос заключается вот в чем:

- Возможно ли, что валидный объект пересечет границу адресного пространства?

Вопрос касается как виртуальной памяти, так и физической.

Например, такой объект:

```
uint8_t arr[1024];
```

Или такой:

```
uint8_t *arr = malloc(1024);
```

Может ли:

```
&arr[x] > &arr[y]
```

Вернуть `true`, при условии, что `x < y`?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103328/discussion-on-question-by-mgneo-------).

Answer (score 6):

`uint_t arr[1024]` теоретически может пересечь границу выделенного ОС блока памяти, тогда это будет называться переполнением стека (stackoverflow :).

Во втором случае, если в куче не хватит места malloc запросит память у ОС и та выделит очередной блок и метод либо вернет адрес блока, который гарантированно в адресном пространстве процесса, либо вернет NULL если памяти не хватает.

`&arr[x] > &arr[y]` - да, условие всегда истинно если x > y

Что касается физической памяти, то при наличии механизма виртуальных адресов у процессора, ее распределением заведует ОС. Выход за пределы возможен только в случае наличия ошибок в функциях выделения памяти ОС

Comment: «тогда это будет называться переполнением стека» - но всё равно гарантируется, что либо будет выделен непрерывный блок, либо возникнет исключение.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Исключение может не возникнуть, если программа собрана без поддержки определения переполнения стека и процессор/ОС не поддерживают контроля выхода за пределы сегмента. Например в x86 в реальном режиме произойдет заворачивание адресов в начало сегмента и никто этого не заметит, просто что то затрется. программа возможно даже сразу не упадет, но это это уже чистой воды UB. И кстати исключение возникнет только при попытке использования этой переменной, но ни при ее объявлении, потому что память в стеке как то особо не выделяется, меняется указатель стека и все